# Algoritmo de Multiplicação por soma para qualquer número inteiro

Tags: python

Eu tenho que desenvolver um algoritmo de multiplicação por soma para qualquer número inteiro, da forma mais otimizada possível.

Eu pensei no seguinte: `x*y=z;x,y` pertence aos inteiros, logo `z=x+x y` vezes. Eu não sei praticamente nada de programação, mas consegui chegar nessas linhas:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite um número'))
n2= int(input('Digite um número'))
multiplicação = (n1 + n1) range (n2)
print("A multiplicação de", n1, "(n1 + n1) range (n", n2, "eh igual a", multiplicação)
```

O meu problema é que eu não consigo definir a lei de multiplicação como `n1+n1 n2` vezes. Preciso que alguém me de uma luz nesse aspecto, só preciso dessa definição. O calculo ainda deve ser feito da forma mais otimizada possível ex:

```
5.2=5+5
```

não:

```
5.2=2+2+2+2+2
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia disso também eu ficaria extremamente grato.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Algoritmo de multiplicação por soma no Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/296577/algoritmo-de-multiplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o-por-soma-no-python)

Comment: Refiz minha pergunta,aquela não estava bem feita,eu preciso apenas da transcrição de n1+n1 n2 vezes para o python.

Comment: Dê uma olhada neste [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/299251/como-multiplicar-em-python-sem-o-operador-multiplica%c3%a7%c3%a3o).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minha outra resposta já responde isso, é só fazer uma verificação para saber qual valor é maior:

```
n1 = int(input('Digite um número'))

n2 = int(input('Digite um número'))

# Cria uma variável que vai receber um valor booleano (true = positivo, false = negativo)
sinal = True

# Verifica se um dos números é negativo, se for muda o valor de sinal para false (negativo)
if (n1 < 0) != (n2 < 0):
    sinal = False

# Muda o sinal de n1 para positivo se ele for negativo
if n1 < 0:
    n1 *= -1

# Muda o sinal de n2 para positivo se ele for negativo
if n2 < 0:
    n2 *= -1

resultado = 0

if n1 > n2:
    for i in range(n2):
        resultado += n1
else:
    for i in range(n1):
        resultado += n2

# Se o sinal for false transforma o resultado para negativo
if sinal == False:
    resultado *= -1

print("A multiplicação de", n1, "(n1 + n1) range (n", n2, "eh igual a", resultado)
```

Uma expressão `n *= -1` é o mesmo que `n = n * -1`

Comment: A parte da otimização sim,mas amigo a linha "(n1 + n1) range (n2)" está errada,é isso que eu não consigo fazer,ainda não consegui transcrever para o python n1+n1 n2 vezes,eu quero saber como fazer essa linha,já que a que eu fiz está errada.

Comment: Editei a resposta, acredito que é o mais próximo possível

Comment: Ainda tem que definir a multiplicação,que é o que eu não sei

Comment: O que seria _"definir a multiplicação"_?

Comment: "print("A multiplicação de", n1, "(n1 + n1) range (n", n2, "eh igual a", resultado)" A multiplicação não está definida como nada,como estava antes erroneamente e como eu venho tentando definir como n1+n1 n2 vezes.

Comment: troque `multiplicação` por `resultado` como na resposta

Comment: n1 = int(input('Digite um número'))

n2= int(input('Digite um número'))

resultado = 0

if n1 > n2:
    for n1 in range(n2):
        resultado += n1
else:
    for n2 in range(n1):
        resultado += n2

print("resultado ", n1, "(n1 + n1) range (n", n2, "eh igual a", resultado) Dessa forma não funciona,como seria? Desculpa minha ignorância

Comment: Editei a resposta com a correção

Comment: Muito obrigado mano! Sério obrigado por toda sua paciência,só tenho a agradecer,extremamente grato!

Comment: Só mais uma dúvida,tem como por para funcionar com número negativo?

Comment: Editei a resposta com uma explicação

Comment: Mano sem sacanagem,você é deus! O único que teve a paciência de me ajudar,só tenho a agradecer,muito obrigado msm! De coração!!!! Extremamente grato! Desculpa qualquer coisa!

Comment: Não sou deus apenas estou numa situação parecida contigo, apesar de manjar em php, javascript... estou iniciando em python, na verdade eu que tenho que agradecer, estou aprendendo ensinando, graças a essa pergunta aprendi sobre booleanos, loops e operador xor no Python

Comment: Mano só tenho a agradecer mesmo,meu professor passou esse trabalho valendo 10 pontos,sem explicar porra nenhuma,ficou falando da família dele três aulas,obrigado por tudo msm!

Comment: Você usa algo especifico para estudo e pesquisas? Algum site?

Comment: Como eu sei como fazer em outra linguagem eu busco pelo nome na outra linguagem em python no google, por exemplo "array python", em js e php é array no python é list

Comment: Ah entendi,de qualquer forma muito obrigado!