# Como multiplicar em Python sem o operador multiplicação?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Tenho uma tarefa e estou com dificuldade em concluí-la. O que fiz foi o seguinte:

```
m= int(input('Digite o primeiro fator:'))
n= int(input('Digite o segundo fator:'))

def multiplica(numero):
    while m > 0:
        print (n + multiplica (m-1) n)
def multiplicaneg(numero):
    while m < 0:
        print ((-n) + multiplica (m+1) n)

if m or n == 0:
    print (0)
elif m > 0:
    return multiplica
else:
    return multiplicaneg
```

O que tentei foi criar uma função pra multiplicar e depois, na hora de imprimir, retornar a função com o resultado adequado.

Comment: Muito bom seu código, mas não consegui entende-lo. POderia me explicar o que está acontecendo no código? Porque eu mesma queria fazer o código, entende? Perceber a ideia  e criar os meus :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Isso tudo pode ser feito a partir de uma só função e sem recursividade, usando valores absolutos [`abs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#abs):

```
def multiplica(i, j):
  res = 0
  while i > 0:
      res += j
      i -= 1
  return res

i = int(input('Digite o primeiro fator:')) # 11
j = int(input('Digite o segundo fator:')) # -356

res = multiplica(abs(i), abs(j)) # usamos os valores absolutos de ambos, mais tarde verificamos se vai ser negativo ou positivo
if(i < 0 < j or j < 0 < i):
  res = -res

print('{} * {} = {}'.format(i, j, res)) # 11 * -356 = -3916
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/WrongJudiciousMeasurements)

Caso optes por continuar a usar recursividade:

```
def multiplica(i, j):
  if(j == 0 or i == 0):
    return i
  return i + multiplica(i, j-1)

i = int(input('Digite o primeiro fator:')) # 11
j = int(input('Digite o segundo fator:')) # -356

res = multiplica(abs(i), abs(j)) - i # usamos os valores absolutos de ambos, mais tarde verificamos se vai ser negativo ou positivo
if(i < 0 < j or j < 0 < i):
  res = -res

print('{} * {} = {}'.format(i, j, res)) # 11 * -356 = -3916
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/repls/EvergreenPrizeObject)

Comment: "res += j" ? Nunca tinha visto essa sintaxe, o que significa?

Comment: Estamos a incrementar na própria variável a que estamos a atribuir o valor, é o mesmo que `res = res + j`, neste caso é por facilitismo (escrever menos)

Comment: Muito obrigada, acho que começo a entender o código. Última dúvida: dá pra aproveitar alguma coisa do meu código? :/

Comment: @PaulaJaquelineSilva por lapso meu esqueci-me de cobrir a hipotese de ambos serem negativos (dá positivo), mas está corrigido, dsculpa. No caso desta resposta consegui aproveitar `int(input('Digite o primeiro fator:'))`, o `while` e quase o nome da função d: , e os nomes das variáveis podes colocar como quiseres

Answer (score 3):

Outra opção é utilizar a função nativa `sum`:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    result = sum(b for _ in range(abs(a)))
    return result if a > 0 else -result
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/AncientAustereArchitect) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Y0CLIR) | [GitHub GIST](https://gist.github.com/0ad843a734c9260201c1744104db730a)</sup>

Em que será somado o valor de `b` uma quantidade igual ao valor absoluto de `a`, independente do sinal de `b`, pois somar números negativos resulta em um número negativo. A única questão é se deverá inverter o sinal do resultado conforme o sinal de `a`. Se positivo, mantém o sinal, mas, se negativo, inverte.

Assim:

```
print(multiply(2, 5))   # 10
print(multiply(-2, -5)) # 10

print(multiply(-2, 5))  # -10
print(multiply(2, -5))  # -10
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta questão traz à tona a própria definição de `multiplicação`.

**O que é multiplicação?**

A multiplicação nada mais é do que `soma` de `parcelas iguais`.

Exemplo 1: Quanto é **2 x 4**?

```
 (2 * 4) == 4 + 4 == 8
```

Isto significa que `2 x 4` é a **soma** de `2` parcelas de `4`.

Exemplo 2: quanto é **3 x 9**?

```
(3 * 9) == 9 + 9 + 9 == 27
```

Isto significa que `3 x 9` é a **soma** de `3` parcelas de `9`.

Se aceitarmos a condição que a `multiplicação` no conjunto dos números reais é `comutativa`, podemos dizer que:

```
(2 * 4) == (4 * 2) == 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 == 8
```

Isto é, `4 x 2` é a `soma` de `4` parcelas de `2` e...

```
(3 * 9) == (9 * 3) == 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 + 3 == 27
```

Isto é, `9 x 3` é a `soma` de `9` parcelas de `3`.

Agora, com esta explicação fica muito mais fácil implementar um `laço de repetição` para calcular o produto entre dois `fatores` sem utilizar o `operador` de `multiplicação`.

Se quiser utilizar o laço `for` para resolver esta questão, pode utilizar o seguinte algoritmo...

```
f1 = int(input('Digite o primeiro fator: '))
f2 = int(input('Digite o segundo fator: '))

soma = 0
for c in range(f1, f2 + f1):
    soma += f1
print(f'\033[32mO produto é: {soma}')
```

Observe o funcionamento do algoritmo no [repl.it](https://repl.it/join/naxlebuv-solkarped)

Observe que `f1` é o primeiro fator e `f2` é o segundo fator.

Answer (score -1):

Tenho uma resposta nessa forma, porem funciona apenas para numeros naturais.

```py
n1=int(input("Fator:"))
n2=int(input("Fator:"))
x=1
soma=n1
while x<n2:
    soma=soma+n1
    x=x+1
print(f"Resultado: {soma}")
```

Comment: Na verdade não funciona para o caso de `n2` ser igual a zero, pois a resposta deveria ser zero e sempre será `n1`