# Como calcular potenciação apenas utilizando a operação de soma?

Tags: python, matemática

Eu teria feito um código que faz multiplicação a partir da soma, mas eu gostaria de saber como posso fazer potencia pela soma, sem a utiliza vezes(*).

```py
x = (input('Digite um número: '))
y = (input('Digite um segundo número: '))
x = float(x)
y = float(y)

soma = 0
num = 0
while (num < x):
    soma = soma + y
    num = num + 1
    print("Seu resultado é: "+str(soma))
```

Answer (score 2):

A potenciação nada mais é que múltiplas operações de multiplicação, então podes implementar a multiplicação através de somas e utilizá-la para potenciação. Por sorte isso já foi discutido aqui na comunidade:

- [Como multiplicar em Python sem o operador multiplicação?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/299251/5878)

Vale notar que para que seja possível esse tipo de operação os dois operandos necessitarão ser inteiro, pois a multiplicação A*B por soma nada mais é que o número A somado B vezes (ou o número B somado A vezes) e a potenciação é a forma análoga, com a operação de multiplicação: A multiplicado B vezes (ou B multiplicado A vezes).

Também, assumindo que a ideia é não utilizar o operador de multiplicação também não poderemos utilizar o operador de divisão; assim a potenciação com expoentes negativos não serão possíveis, dado que o expoente negativo nada mais é que uma representação da fração da base invertida, o que geraria uma operação de divisão.

Também, não há limitações quanto ao sinal da base, podendo ser tanto positiva quanto negativa. Assim:

```
def multiply(a, b):
    result = sum(b for _ in range(abs(a)))
    return result if a > 0 else -result

def pow(base, exponent):
    result = 1
    for _ in range(exponent):
        result = multiply(result, base)
    return result
```

Para testar:

```
tests = [
  (2, 3),   # Base positiva
  (-3, 5),  # Base negativa
  (1, 99),  # Base igual a um
  (0, 2),   # Base igual a zero
  (5, 0),   # Expoente igual a zero
]

for base, exponent in tests:
  assert pow(base, exponent) == base**exponent, \
    f"{pow(base, exponent)} é diferente de {base**exponent}"
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-398644)</sup>

Como nenhuma saída é produzida ao executar, todas as condições em `assert` foram validadas, o que mostra que o retorno da função `pow` foi o mesmo que o operador nativo da linguagem.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode seguir a mesma lógica.

Se para multiplicar você percorre um loop n número de vezes, onde n é o multiplicador, e soma o multiplicando ao resultado.

Para exponenciar você precisa percorrer um loop n - 1 número de vezes, onde n é o expoente, mas ao invés de somar, você reatribui ao resultado o valor da multiplicação.

Exemplo:

```
def multiplicar(x, y):
    resultado = x
    for _ in range(y-1):
        resultado += x
    return resultado

def exponenciar(x, y):
    resultado = x
    for _ in range(y-1):
        resultado = multiplicar(resultado, x)
    return resultado

print(f"Seu resultado é: {multiplicar(2, 5)}") # 10
print(f"Seu resultado é: {exponenciar(2, 5)}") # 32
```

Comment: Como este código se comporta quando uma ou mais entradas forem negativas?

Comment: Pow in Python: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pow-in-python/

Comment: @Anderson, da mesma forma que se comporta se o multiplicador for negativo: não funciona. O código original não tinha tratamento de erros, e honestamente, não acho necessário se preocupar com isso em um código que nunca será utilizado seriamente em produção.